# Loading Twitter Dataset into python or database

Tags: python, json

Just downloaded the twitter dataset spritzer edition from here https://archive.org/details/archiveteam-twitter-stream-2014-09, now wondering if there is an automated way to load this into python or any database. I found there were multiple folders after unzipping and these also contain more archives. What i sthe quickest way to load everything seamlessly into python?

Comment: You do realize Python has built-in tools to handle Json. Right? https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: Yep.....but is there a way to automatically unzip all the folders and subfolders instead of doing it one by one

Comment: Look at glob and zipfile.